# Is it valid to say $(P \equiv Q)\iff(P\iff Q)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know that we can conclude  $P \iff Q$  is true when $P \equiv Q$; this has made me wonder whether $(P \equiv Q) \iff (P \iff Q)$ is always true - I have doubts because if $(P \iff Q)$ is true, this doesn't tell us whether $P$ always has the same value as $Q$ for all possible values of P and Q(we only know they have the same value for these specific values of P and Q ), and my understanding of logical equivalence is that two statements are logically equivalent if they have the same value in all possible assignments of values to their propositional variables . So is this a valid statement?

Comment: You have to specify what symbol stand for what: you are playing with [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) and with [Bi-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional). Mathematical symbols are useful exactly in order to avoid the above confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not. Mainly because logical equivalence is a metalogical symbol, while a logical statement should only use logical symbols. Moreover, even if the biconditional in the middle is a tarski biconditional that still wouldnt be true. $P\equiv Q$ is a stronger condition. As you can have models of a theory that have $P\iff Q$ being true. But $P\equiv Q$ is true only if in each and every model of the theory or logic $P\iff Q$ is true.